# tailwindcss 2.0 is not working on laravel 8

Tags: laravel

1 installed tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
2 added directives to resource/css/app.css
3  upgraded laravel-mix 5.1 to 6 beta

when i run npm run dev

```
✔ Compiled Successfully in 8498ms
```

┌───────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ File                              │ Size     │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ /js/app.js                        │ 593 KiB  │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ css/app.css                       │ 61 bytes

it's just not working. No errors, no nothing

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Posty</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
</head>
<body class="p-6 bg-gray-200">
    <nav class="p-6 bg-white flex justify-between mb-6">
        <ul class="flex items-center">
            <li>
                <a href="/" class="p-3">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="p-3">Dashboars</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('posts') }}" class="p-3">Post</a>
            </li>
        </ul> ```
````

Comment: You should probably add some code so that someone can help you

Comment: Hello, maybe this post should help you https://devdojo.com/thinkverse/laravel-quickie-how-to-install-and-build-tailwindcss-v2-with-laravel-mix#tailwindcss-v2-and-laravel-mix-6-beta

Comment: I get the same thing. There is simply no content from tailwind included in /public/css/app.css